# Smooth toric compactification of $\mathbb C^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, toric-varieties, compactifications

By a *compactification* $(X,Y)$ of $\mathbb C^n$, we mean an irreducible compact complex space $X$ and a closed analytic subspace $Y\subset X$ such that $X\setminus Y$ is biholomorphic to $\mathbb C^n$. Then, $Y$ is automatically a hypersurface.
A reference I found on this subject is: *Compactifications of $\mathbb C^n$: A survey*, by T Peternell and M Schneider.

The most general case should be very difficult. But, let's start with a simple case. If we further assume $X$ is a *smooth toric variety*, can we classify all possible compactifications of $\mathbb C^n$? For example, when $n=2$, the space $X$ can be $\mathbb P^2$, $\mathbb P^1\times \mathbb P^1$, and a Hirzebruch surface.

Comment: The answer is "yes" if you also want $Y$ to be fixed by the torus action. Toric varieties are classified by polyhedral fans (see any book on the subject), and what you want is to classify complete fans $\Sigma\subseteq \mathbf{R}^n$ which contain the standard cone $[0,\infty)^n$. 

Already in dimension $2$ you will see that there is many more than those you have listed: every finite set $S$ of irreducible vectors in $\mathbf{Z}^2$ not contained in a halfspace and such that $S\cap [0,\infty)^2 = \{(0,1), (1, 0)\}$ will give you a different example.

Comment: P.S. I now noticed that you want $X$ to be smooth. Then the above applies, but now we want every cone of the fan spanned by a basis of $\mathbf{Z}^n$. In dimension two, this means a sequence of vectors $(0, 1)  =v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_m=(1, 0)$ with increasing slope, not all contained in a half-space, and such that every pair $(v_{i-1}, v_{i})$ spans  $\mathbf{Z}^2$. There is plenty of those (take any $S$ as above and apply "toric resolution of singularities" which in this case will mean "continued fractions expansions of rational numbers are finite").

Comment: @PiotrAchinger Thank you so much. You're right. There will be plenty of them. Maybe we should add some extra conditions. For example, what if we further require $X\setminus Y$ is a nef divisor in $X$?

Comment: *Any* smooth projective toric variety is a compactification of $\mathbf{C}^n$, because its toric open chart corresponding to a maximal cone will be affine smooth toric variety without torus factors, hence isomorphic $\mathbf{C}^n$.